# Find Control Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I have created

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" >
```

using literal.  Now i want to get this control so i can check if its checked or not.  How do I find this control in the aspx.cs page?

Comment: can you give some detail

Comment: i am using a panel...than i create a literal in at at runtime and assign literal.text = "<input type="checkbox" id="forum1"">.. now i want to find is the checkbox is checked or not how can i find it ? i cant find it ..i tried using findcontrol...any help?

Answer (score 5):

if you want to find control on code behind file , then you should set this as runat="server",

```
literal.text = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"forum1\" runat=\"server\">";



HtmlInputCheckBox test = (HtmlInputCheckBox) Page.FindControl("test");
```

but whenever page is going to postback you lost state of this control.

May this will give you right solution
http://www.codeasp.net/blogs/SumitArora/microsoft-net/841/value-of-dynamic-textbox-lost-on-postback

You can use page init event to generate control

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{ 
  HtmlInputCheckbox test = new HtmlInputCheckbox ();
  test.id= "test";                 
  pnlControl.Controls.Add(test);
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you created it programmatically as a literal, you can't use FindControl to find it.  When the form posts back, you can use the form collection to see if the value posted back, as in:

```
Request.Form["test"]
```

or

```
Request["test"]
```

If the user doesn't check the checkbox, then the form value will not be present, which is something the  uses a hidden field to work around.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to search for a server control for which you have specified the id parameter.

```
Control ctrl = FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Page.Controls.FindControl()
```

or

```
Page.YourFormNameHEre.Controls.FindControl()
```